# How to add custom claims in asp.net containing external authentication service?

Tags: c#, jwt, openid-connect

I'm setting up a new dotnet project with OpenId-Connect and Cookie base authentication. The token which I am receiving from some authentication server(like azure ad) is based on RS256 symmetric. 
I have two questions:

1st How to add custom variables in the token which is in RS256.

2nd How to maintain them in cookie?

I've tried with JWT.Serializers but always get stuck at one point or other.

```
    IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
    IDateTimeProvider provider = new UtcDateTimeProvider();
    IJwtValidator validator = new JwtValidator(serializer, provider);
    IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
    var algo = new JWT.Algorithms.RSAlgorithmFactory(() => new 
    Class1().GetByThumbprint("C11B7AF7C7910DEEB2273996BAB6033D73F6DC61"));
    IJwtDecoder decoder = new JwtDecoder(serializer, validator, urlEncoder, algo);
```

Don't know whether to continue with this.
Also with HS256 it was easy to edit the token on https://jwt.io/ I am not able to do that with RS256.

Startup.Auth.cs

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(
        new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            LoginPath = Microsoft.Owin.PathString.FromUriComponent("/Account/SignIn")
        });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        });
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions has something in Notifications where I can intercept token and add my custom token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

## 1st How to add custom variables in the token which is in RS256.

You don't need to. Tokens received from external service with OpenId connect is basically for authentication and not for authorization. We may use multiple external authentication service, adding custom claims here will not be the good idea and neither it should be done.

## 2nd How to maintain them in cookie?

This is the place were we may modify our token. Cookie is not in same symmetric cipher as that of external authentication service. We my intercept the cookie authentication method to add custom claims.

Here is how I did it:

#### CustomSecureDataFormat.cs

```
public class CustomSecureDataFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
{
    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        }
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        //Custom claim
        claims.Add(new Claim("HairCount", "46"));
        data.Identity.AddClaims(claims);
        string audienceId = AzureADConstants.GraphResourceId;
        Guid guidClientId;
        bool isValidAudience = Guid.TryParse(AzureADConstants.ClientId, out guidClientId);
        if (!isValidAudience)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("AuthenticationTicket.Properties does not include audience");
        }

        var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(AzureADConstants.AppKey);
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyByteArray);
        var signingCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(
            securityKey,
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
        var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
        string _issuer = AzureADConstants.Authority;
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingCredentials);
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        return handler.WriteToken(token);
    }

    public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(protectedText))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("protectedText");
        }

        var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(AzureADConstants.AppKey);
        var securityKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(keyByteArray);
        var signingCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(
            securityKey,
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityToken = handler.ReadToken(protectedText);
        string rawToken = ((JwtSecurityToken)securityToken).RawData;

        string audienceId = AzureADConstants.GraphResourceId;

        var validationParams = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ValidAudience = audienceId,
            ValidIssuer = audienceId,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            TokenDecryptionKey = securityKey,
            IssuerSigningKey = securityKey
        };
        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        var principal = handler.ValidateToken(rawToken, validationParams, out validatedToken);
        var identity = principal.Identities;

        return new AuthenticationTicket(identity.First(), new AuthenticationProperties());
    }
}
```

#### Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
    LoginPath = Microsoft.Owin.PathString.FromUriComponent("/Account/SignIn"),
    TicketDataFormat = new CustomSecureDataFormat()
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution. It works but has some flaws: 1st Sliding expiration does not works with your solution. 2nd Cookie should be encrypted. 3rd where does refresh token goes?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question,

```
private string GenerateAccessJwt()
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();       

    SigningCredentials credentials = new SigningCredentials("your sign key", SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);

    JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "Your issuer",
        audience: "Your audience",
        claims: new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim("OneClaim", "Hey I am a custom claim."),
        },
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1) //Short expiration for access token,
        signingCredentials: credentials);

    return handler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

This snippet should do the trick, you have to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn464181(v%3Dvs.114)

Is working for me on NET Standard 2.0.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: I added SymmetricSecurityKey in SigningCredentials and I used private key for this     `var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Startup.appKey));
            SigningCredentials credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);` Didn't work

Comment: I was wondering if OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions has something in Notifications where I can intercept token and add my custom token.